# Diablo II Rune Words - Can you make Call to Arms using a Five Socketed Bow

Tags: diablo-ii

I am now playing Diablo II Resurrected.  I found a five socketed diamond bow, and I note that *Call to Arms* is a five socketed rune word that can be put into 5 socketed weapons.

But, I can't remember how Blizzard classified weapons (unless they say polearm, like for Insight, or Swords for Ancients Pledge). (Coming back to the game after years of not playing).

When it requires "a weapon" for that rune word, is that "any melee weapon" or is that also inclusive of bows (any weapon)?  I do note that some rune words call for missile weapons and those are mostly bow or cross bow rune words.

Is Call to Arms a rune word that I can make with a five socketed Diamond Bow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Diablo wiki](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Call_to_Arms) it works for "All Ranged & Melee Weapons."  So yes, you can put it in a bow if you really wanted to, but I would highly recommend finding a 1 handed weapon to put it in as the bow is a 2 handed weapon and will limit you from potentially dual wielding it with another + skill weapon in the future for even better war cries.

And as an additional confirmation, here is a screen shot of call to arms in a bow:

[image: CTA Bow]

Comment: +1 about preferring one handed weapons for this runeword, there are plenty of shields with “+ all skills”

Comment: Thanks, the screen shot clenches it.  Appreciate it.